# 2.9x Why can't I see my scripted print function results in the console?

Tags: python, scripting

```
import bpy
print ("something")
```

When I run this script nothing happens, nothing appears.

The only answers to where it prints I find are from 6 years ago.

With 2.91 It's not in the Python Console output in the Scripting tab, so where does it display its print command?

Using Windows.

Comment: I'm not on windows, but the console is an actual console or terminal (whatever is called in windows), accessible from the menu. It is not any window within blender.

Comment: [how do I get the console in windows](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/how-do-i-get-the-console-on-windows) and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/launch/windows.html

Answer (score 4):

Things have not changed from 6 years ago. The console is not a window that is part of the blender's user interface, but one that belongs to the operating system.

### In widows

You can enable the system console from blender using the top menu's  *Window* > *Toggle System Console*.

[image]

That will open a totally different window, with the console and all messages from python will appear there.

[image]

---

### In Linux

There is no option to open a terminal window from within blender, the terminal window must be opened before and the blender program should be run from terminal.

[image]

On Mint/Cinnamon, the app launcher can be set to Launch in terminal. That way the terminal window is always available.

[image]

Comment: what about on macOS?? macOS there also no system console option in window. And it can not running from system terminal.

Comment: For macOS, open the terminal and navigate to the Applications folder (where Blender.app is located). Then issue this command to open Blender from the terminal: ./Blender.app/Content/MacOS/blender