Having issues with Geo Nodes Dependency Cycle
Having the curve modifiers not working properly with geo nodes.
The coloured objects are dictating where the objects are to be placed along the "PCG" curve
I want to have a curve modifier on the placement objects so that if I change the curve, these objects will follow along.
However it seems that only 1 curve modifier is working at a given time.
The objects do follow the curve but nothing gets displayed.
eg. in the 2nd picture, only the purple object has the curve modifier, and it works as expected.
but in the 3rd picture, both the purple and red objects have the same modifier, but only 1 of the instanced objects is being displayed.
I get the error
"Can't access object's geometry because it's not evaluated yet. This can happen when there is a dependency cycle"
I would like to not have to apply the curve modifier




Can you tell us what message you have in the console about cyclic dependencies, if any ? (see here if you are using Windows OS : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23147/how-do-i-get-the-console-on-windows). Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

My guess would be to attach the GN modifier to the default Cube e.g., and to input the PCG curve as "external" object, using an Object Info node to recover the curve geometry. This way, the curve will be at the root of a tree with two independent branches, one carrying the Curve modifier, the other carrying the GN modifier, without circular dependency.
